# Помогите перевести слова на кресте

Tags: переводы, анализ-текста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это нательный крест. Что означают слова на нём?

Answer (score 1):

На кресте написано по церковно-славянски:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Русскими буквами: *"да воскреснет Бог и расточатся врази его"*.

"Да" означает "пусть", "расточатся" — "рассеются", а "врази" — "враги".

Это начало одной из вечерних молитв и 67-го псалма (конец молитвы отличается от продолжения псалма).